# How to autfill a column with data from My Site

Tags: 2013, list, calculated-column, people-picker

I would like to create a custom list in SP2013 that would have two `People or Group` columns. One would display the **Name of a user**, the other would display his **email address of the same user** (both information are available in this column type - I assume they are taken somewhere from MySite).

Is there any way how to make the content of the other column display automatically? i.e, When I select **User A** in the first column, I wouldn't have to manually add his email address to the second column but it would fill automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People normally think of using a **Calculated column** for such requirement, but that will not work. Instead, you may achieve it using **SharePoint Designer Workflow**.

Modify your list design as below,

```
Column Name       |       Type             |          Detail
------------------------------------------------------------------------
User Name         |   People or Group      | To select the required user here
Email ID          |  Single line of text   | Email ID populated automatically
```

Create a SharePoint designer workflow, which will set the **Email ID** column once the item is created. The workflow will run whenever an item is added and modified.

Workflow step,

```
Set Email ID to Current Item:User Name
```

In Current Item:User Name, set the value as

```
Data Source        : Current Item
Field from source  : User Name
Return field as    : Email Address
```

Note: Dont forget to hide/disable your **Email ID** column from the required forms to avoid confusions for end user.